# Polymer core-selector set height and enable scrolling

Tags: scroll, polymer

I have a `core-selector` in a `paper-dialog`. I'd like to set it's height to a fixed value and enable scrolling in case not all of the elements fit the available space. I've googled a lot but without any luck.

Does anybody know how to do this please?

I am using Polymer 0.5

```
<paper-shadow>
    <core-selector on-core-select="{{onSubCapSelect}}">
        <template repeat="{{scap in scaps}}">
            <paper-item name="{{scap.SUBCAPABILITY_ID}}">{{scap.SUBCAPABILITY_NAME}}</paper-item>
        </template>
    </core-selector>
</paper-shadow>
```

Answer (score 0):

use core-list this and set its height.

```
<paper-shadow>
    <core-list on-core-select="{{onSubCapSelect}}" data="{{scaps}}" height="400px">
            <paper-item name="{{model.SUBCAPABILITY_ID}}">{{model.SUBCAPABILITY_NAME}}</paper-item>
    </core-list>
</paper-shadow>
```